# Using an object method to instantiate a new object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to write a method for one object that can create a new instance of a separate object.  Is this possible with javascipt?

```
function Library () {
  this.name = "My Library";
  this.createShelf = function () {
       <some code>
  };
}

function Shelf (shelfNumber) {
  this.shelfNumber = shelfNumber;
}

var myLib = new Library();
myLib.createShelf();
```

Is is possible to create a new instance of Shelf by using a method in Library?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.. you could. Just modify your code to return the `Shelf` Object.

```
function Library () {
   this.name = "My Library";
   this.createShelf = function (n) {
       return new Shelf(n);
   }
}
```

Then you can do this

```
var myLib = new Library();
var shelf = myLib.createShelf(number);
```

Comment: Yes this is working.  I think I was missing the return keyword.  Thank you!

Comment: @jacobbarnett glad to have have helped you :)

Comment: Is there a way to write the method so that the newly created Shelf becomes a property of the Library object?  I'm thinking something like Library.prototype.n

Answer (score 0):

Another possible usage of **Object.create** is to clone immutable objects.

```
    function Library () {
      this.name = "My Library";
      this.createShelf = function () {
       <some code>
  };
}

    var newObject = Object.create(Library());

     newObject.createShelf();
```